# Почему не открыт порт 80 при инициализации Google cloud VM?

Tags: google-cloud, облако

При создании ВМ в гугл консоли хочу постучатся в порт 80 по внешнему ип, но он залокан. Не заходит даже сразу после создания экземпляра — в туториалах все красочно должно работать.

Что я делал:

1. Открывал все возможные порта в правилах фаервола, не помогает.
2. На стороне машины дисаблил фаервол, всё равно 80 порт заюлокирован.

До завтра нужно повесить сервак в прод, вчера весь вечер потратил, идей уже нет, почему все так плохо с портами в гугл.

Стучусь из линуса по команде:

```
telnet [ip] [port]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как по умолчанию можно открыть только порты для исходящих соеденений,как открыть для входящих можно почитать [тут](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/firewall)

Comment: link not workd.

Comment: Что именно не работает, нужно посмотреть ваши настройки.

Comment: Проблема решена. Проблема в Node сервере который не слушал порты, почему так буду еще разбиратся. С апачи все работает как часы.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный порядок действий был бы следующий на мой взгляд :

1. Проверить присутствуют ли у VM, http-server, https-tags , поможет узнать смотреть ли вообще ваша машина во внешнюю сеть.
2. Также можно создать новое firewall-rule и добавить его к вашей VM

> gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-eighty  --allow=tcp:80

3. Добавь созданный тэг

> gcloud compute instances add-tags test3 --tags=allow-eighty